# Associate avalonia app with a certain custom extension and process the file on double click or on Open with option from the finder in osX

Tags: c#, .net, macos, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have created a cross platform desktop application using Avalonia framework. It saves the file in a custom extension lets say (.mcuext). I am able to update the Info.plist and make the finder know that my application supports .mcuext, however I am having a hard time trying to understand as to how to process the file once the user either double clicks on it or tries to open it using “Open with” option from the finder. Currently when I try to do that, it opens up the application but gives me an error saying that My application can not open a file of type .mcuext. I know for a fact that there needs to be an event handler but trying to understand where to put it and how to handle it.
P.S. the processing of the file should only work once the user logs in to the application.

It is not a duplicate of [Associate my app with its custom file type in OSX and open file on double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126150/associate-my-app-with-its-custom-file-type-in-osx-and-open-file-on-double-click)
The answers do not cover my queries about event handling.

Comment: Not really supported out of the box, see https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3822 for a workaround

Comment: @kekekeks Thank you for your reply. I have that implemented already, but still when trying to open the file by right clicking and clicking on Open With it says that the application does not support a file of that extension. Could you please guide me in the right direction, looks like I am missing something.